# Помогите с регистрацией на haltalk.herokuapp.com используя POST запрос

Tags: post

Читаю книгу RESTful Web APIs

На странице 127 предлагается пройти по адресу http://haltalk.herokuapp.com/

На этом сайте написано: добро пожаловать, для регистрации надо выполнить POST запрос

Я никогда не выполнял таких запросов, я не понимаю, как это сделать

На этом же сайте есть кнопка с примером http://haltalk.herokuapp.com/rels/signup

```
POST
Create an account

Request
Headers
The request should have the Content-Type application/json
Body
Required properties
username: string
password: string
Optional properties
bio : string
real_name : string
Example
{
  "username": "fred",
  "password": "pwnme",
  "real_name": "Fred Wilson"
}
        
Responses
201 Created
Headers
Location: URI of the created user account
```

И даже есть оранжевая кнопка для выполнения запроса POST.

Я нажимаю на эту кнопку и в разделе **Body** я передаю имя пользователя и пароль

```
{
  "username": "stackoverflowalex",
  "password": "alexstackoverflow",
  "real_name": "Alex Stackoverflow"
}
```

и нажимаю на кнопочку `Make Request`

в ответ я получаю `500 Internal Server Error` и `We're sorry, but something went wrong`

Я что-то делаю неправильно или не работает сам сервер `haltalk.herokuapp.com` ?

Comment: 500 - ошибка сервера

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подскажите, где ещё так же наглядно можно выполнить POST запрос. Установить себе **postman** ?

Comment: Да, можно постман

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо ! :)

Comment: Postman, HTTPie, да хоть CURL из консоли - любой вариант работает. Можно на js быстро собрать что-нибудь с Axios и посмотреть, как отправляются запросы через консоль разработчика (это уже даже ближе к работе с реальным API фронтендеру).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, на текущий момент [сервер](http://haltalk.herokuapp.com/) **не очень работает**. Если посмотреть историю в [issue](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser/issues/85) в репозитории разработчика, такое уже было. Если интересно посмотреть как работает данная технология, можно "поиграться" с данным [ресурсом](http://api.m.ox.ac.uk/browser/#/courses/).
Также можно попробовать поискать контейнер/виртуалку с halbrowser и "пощупать" его локально, на своей машине. Например вот [такой](https://hub.docker.com/r/jcassee/hal-browser) docker контейнер нормально запускается.

[Документация](https://stateless.group/hal_specification.html)

[Исходники](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser)

[Список ресурсов, есть битые ссылки(!)](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal_specification/wiki/APIs)

p.s. [хорошая статья о REST api](https://guides.hexlet.io/ru/rest-api/)

Comment: спасибо :) большое